# UIAlertView cleaning Root View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a `UIAlertView` that on the button calls a method that adds a popover like view.

The code is like:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [IAPHelper addPurchasePopupWithDelegate: self];
}
```

This method `addPurchasePopupWithDelegate` adds a `UIView` loaded from a XIB to the root view, obtained as follows:

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIView *rootView = window.rootViewController.view;
...
```

Things that I don't want to do different:

- I want to add my view to the root view
- I want to add it after clicking on a button inside my `UIAlertView`

**The problem is that my view shows up and almost immediately disappears. The reason is that when iOS is going to dismiss the `UIAlertView` it cleans up the `window.rootViewController.view` somehow.**

The following has worked:

```
-(void) callIAP {
    [IAPHelper addPurchasePopupWithDelegate: self];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(callIAP) withObject: self afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

But it's not an acceptable solution in my opinion.
The question is, **how can I add a view to the root view inside a `UIAlertView` button callback?**

Everything is being executed in the main thread.

Comment: Use `didDismissWithButtonIndex:` instead of `clickedButtonAtIndex:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I confirmed that in iOS 8 the problem exists. Anyone can simply verify it by running this code block from a view controller

```
@interface ViewController ()<UIAlertViewDelegate>    
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Show alert
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notice" message:@"Adding a view to the root view..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Now!", nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 80)];
    dummyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIView *rootView = window.rootViewController.view;

    [rootView addSubview:dummyView];
}
@end
```

But wait a second... Does it necessary need to be `UIAlertView`? From iOS 8 `UIAlertView` became deprecated. Here is what from [UIAlertView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/):

> Important: UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that
>   UIAlertViewDelegate is also deprecated.) To create and manage alerts
>   in iOS 8 and later, instead use UIAlertController with a
>   preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert.

Switching to `UIAlertController` the code block above will look like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Show alert immediately
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Notice" message:@"Adding a view to the root view..." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *addAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Now!" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [self addDummyView];
    }];
    [alert addAction:addAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)addDummyView {
    UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 80)];
    dummyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIView *rootView = window.rootViewController.view;

    [rootView addSubview:dummyView];
}

@end
```

And it just **works**!

In conclusion, if something has been marked as `deprecated`, don't try to stick with it if there is no special reason. Use what suggested by Apple instead.

Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have to disagree. If I execute after 0.1secs it doesn't work, if it's after 0.5 secs it works. It doesn't sound like an elegant solution to me

Comment: What iOS version are you working on? I will try it out and modify my answer accordingly

Comment: @Tony, now you can see my answer updated. I hope that it helps you in one way or another

Comment: I didnt know it was delegated. I will try your code today or tomorrow. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @Tony I am sure that you can fix the issue. Let me know when you're done :)

Comment: Good to hear that it fixed the issue :)